# Ignore flake8 check for the code with backslash

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

Is there a way to ignore flake8 check for a part of code with `\`? I cannot add `#noqa` after `\`.

For example, here is the code I have. `.config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', os.getenv('spark_driver_max_result_size')) \` is over 79 characters

```
session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName(os.getenv('app_name')) \
    .config('spark.yarn.queue', os.getenv('spark_yarn_queue')) \
    .config('spark.driver.memory', os.getenv('spark_driver_memory')) \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', os.getenv('spark_executor_memory')) \
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', os.getenv('spark_driver_max_result_size')) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

This would not work.

```
session = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName(os.getenv('app_name')) \
    .config('spark.yarn.queue', os.getenv('spark_yarn_queue')) \
    .config('spark.driver.memory', os.getenv('spark_driver_memory')) \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', os.getenv('spark_executor_memory')) \
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', os.getenv('spark_driver_max_result_size')) \  # noqa: E501
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: And if you put the `#noqa` after the `.getOrCreate()`?

Comment: Still get `test.py:7:80: E501 line too long (86 > 79 characters)` by putting `#noqa` after `.getOrCreate()`

Comment: If you are unhappy with the default line length: `--max-line-length=n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap you expression in parentheses, and then use newlines normally in those parentheses

```
session = (SparkSession 
    .builder 
    .appName(os.getenv('app_name')) 
    .config('spark.yarn.queue', os.getenv('spark_yarn_queue')) 
    .config('spark.driver.memory', os.getenv('spark_driver_memory')) 
    .config('spark.executor.memory', os.getenv('spark_executor_memory')) 
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', os.getenv('spark_driver_max_result_size')) # noqa: E501
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate())
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to get flake to stop complaining, I would suggest breaking the line with something like:

```
session = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName(os.getenv('app_name'))
    .config('spark.yarn.queue', os.getenv('spark_yarn_queue'))
    .config('spark.driver.memory', os.getenv('spark_driver_memory'))
    .config('spark.executor.memory', os.getenv('spark_executor_memory'))
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', 
            os.getenv('spark_driver_max_result_size'))
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

[PEP8 says](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times. For example, long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:

Comment: Have any idea how to use a `noqa` comment in the one case where implicit continuation can't be used in Python2, with multiple with-statements?